# Autonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes

> Exercise 2. Consider the autonomous system
>   $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
> u_{1}'=u_{2}\\
> u_{2}'=-u_{2}^{3}-u_{1}
> \end{array}\right.$$
>   and the function $V(u_{1}, u_{2})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by
>   $$
> V(u_{1}, u_{2})=u_{1}^{2}+u_{2}^{2}.
> $$
>
> 1. Find the linearization of this system at $0$. Can one directly deduce from properties of this linear system the stability/unstability of the trivial solution $u\equiv 0$ of the given system?
> 2. Let $u(x)=(u_{1}(x),u_{2}(x))$ be a maximal solution of the given system defined on a maximal interval of existence $I=(a,b)$. Show that $V(u(x))$ is a decreasing function on $I.$
> 3. Deduce that the right end point $b$ of $I$ is$+\infty$ and the trivial solution $u\equiv 0$ is Lyapounov stable.
> 4. Show that if $u\not\equiv 0$ then $V(u(x))$ is strictly decreasing in $(a,+\infty)$.
> 5. Show that $u(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $ x\rightarrow\infty$. Hint: use a function $W(u)=V(u)+\epsilon u_{1}^{3}u_{2}$ with some constant $\epsilon>0$ small enough.
> 6. Deduce that all the solutions of the given system are asymptotically stable.

I am able to find what is the linearzation of the system at $0$. But the rest of part(1) and the other parts I am unsure.

Comment: I think the linearization at $0$ is a rotation matrix. What can you say about the stability / instability of a linear system with a rotation matrix?